# Conditionally add Output clause to Merge Statement

Tags: sql-server, merge, conditional-statements

I have a merge statement that I want to output the "id" field if it exists. Currently, I have a statement that outputs whatever id is updated or deleted, but this breaks if there is no column named id. Is there a way to add a condition to the merge statement? Here is the merge statement (disregard the source data values as they are just placeholders):

```
    MERGE PACWARE.DHS.SVDDME WITH (HOLDLOCK) as target
USING (VALUES(<code>,<address1>,'',<city>,<state>,<zip>,0x414c414e205348414c4f534b59)) AS source
([CODE_],[TEMPADD1],[TEMPADD2],[TEMPCITY],[TEMPSTATE],[TEMPZIP],[ATTENTION])
ON target.CODE_ = source.CODE_
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
target.[CODE_] = source.[CODE_],target.[TEMPADD1] = source.[TEMPADD1],target.[TEMPADD2] = source.[TEMPADD2],target.[TEMPCITY] = source.[TEMPCITY],target.[TEMPSTATE] = source.[TEMPSTATE],target.[TEMPZIP] = source.[TEMPZIP],target.[ATTENTION] = source.[ATTENTION]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT([CODE_],[TEMPADD1],[TEMPADD2],[TEMPCITY],[TEMPSTATE],[TEMPZIP],[ATTENTION])
values(source.[CODE_],source.[TEMPADD1],source.[TEMPADD2],source.[TEMPCITY],source.[TEMPSTATE],source.[TEMPZIP],source.[ATTENTION])
OUTPUT INSERTED.id;
```

Comment: This will take some amount of dynamic SQL for not much perceivable benefit

Comment: Thanks for the answer Richard, I am just going to force the users to pass the column they want returned instead of trying to get just an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to handle this at the application layer (by conditionally adding an Output line to the function). This was simpler than trying to find an identifying column and outputting that. The user simply passes the the field they want returned.